# Custom Cipher Encrypt/Decrypt Stream

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

This is my first question here, so if you have anything I can improve on (posts as well as coding style) I'm happy to know.

I know that my coding is the very efficient, so I'll happily take your advises and improvements.

Currently, I'm writing an `AtbashCipher` program, which has to encrypt and decrypt the input `String`. As with every tasks at University, there are some guidelines, which we need to follow, but I'm going to explain my current code first:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class AtbashCipher {

    StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder("");
    String inputString;
    String coded;

    public String getInputString() {
        return this.inputString;
    }

    public void setInputString(String inputString) {
        this.inputString = inputString;
    }

    public String getCoded() {
        return this.coded;
    }

    public void setCoded(String coded) {
        this.coded = coded;
    }

    public char encode(char c) {
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char help = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        if (alphabet.indexOf(help) >= 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
                if (help == alphabet.toLowerCase().charAt(i)) {
                    c = alphabet.charAt(26 - i - 1);
                    code.append(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            code.append(c);
        }

        if (inputString.length() == code.length()) {
            System.out.println("Encode: " + code);
            coded = code.toString();
            inputString = coded;
            code.setLength(0);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public char decode(char c) {
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char help = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        if (alphabet.indexOf(help) >= 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
                if (help == alphabet.toLowerCase().charAt(i)) {
                    c = alphabet.charAt(26 - i - 1);
                    code.append(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            code.append(c);
        }

        if (inputString.length() == code.length()) {
            coded = code.toString();
            inputString = coded;
            System.out.println("Decode: " + code);
            code.setLength(0);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        AtbashCipher atb = new AtbashCipher();
        System.out.print("To be translated: ");
        atb.setInputString(sc.nextLine());
        sc.close();
        for (int j = 0; j < atb.getInputString().length(); j++) {
            char help = atb.getInputString().charAt(j);
            atb.encode(help);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < atb.getInputString().length(); k++) {
            char help = atb.getInputString().charAt(k);
            atb.decode(help);
        }
    }
}
```

This code encrypts and decrypts the inputString, which is still need to replace with a Scanner-Input, but that's not a problem.
We need to bring the methods decode and encode, which are basically the same in my code, but we need to split it anyway. Am I doing something wrong?
(see edit, yes, I did something wrong.)

The problem starts with the task: 
 We need to write a class `AtbashWriter` that implements the `java.io.Writer` and following that, the constructor needs to get these arguments:

```
public AtbashWriter(Writer base, AtbashCipher cipher)
```

Also, we need to override the `write`, `flush` and `close` methods, given by Java.

```
public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
public void flush()
public void close()
```

We need to do the same for the `Reader` as well.

I'm really struggling at getting behind this concept of creating my own `Stream` and implementing it into my code.

Can you please explain to me how that works and how my code could be more efficient? Errors etc. ?

Please don't just link the java library, because I have some difficulties at understanding the concept from libraries, I always look up some examples.

This task is from the University, but I don't get any grades on this, I just want to do it and practice for the exam.

Every help is appreciated.
Thank you :)

Edit: I can't edit the first line of my post, so... hey guys.
Edit2: I just saw that my methods are NOT fully functioning the way i want them, I'll try to correct them.
Edit3: I edited the program, trying to post the Writer maybe today.

Edit4: Late, but still not forgotten: I finished it and added it in here, problem is solved :)

```
private Reader base;
private AtbashCipher cipher;

public AtbashReader(Reader base, AtbashCipher cipher) {
    this.base = base;
    this.cipher = cipher;
}

public int read (char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException{
    int result= base.read(cbuf, off, len);

    for(int i = off; i < (off+len); i++){
        cbuf[i] = cipher.decode(cbuf[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

public void close()throws IOException {
    base.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to make an analogy. Suppose you have already have a machine that is able to repaint cars. It's simple: you give it a car, and the machine paints it. This machine is the equivalent of a `Writer`, that takes a char array, and writes it.

Now, the problem is that cars need to be washed before being painted. So, how could you make a machine that washes cars, and then paints it. You could build a new machine from scratch. Or you could just build a machine that reuses the painting machine. Your machine would take a car, wash it (that's your job), and then give the washed car to the already existing machine. This big machine is your `AtbashWriter`: it writes char arrays, but before writing them, it encodes them. And how does it do that? By encoding the char array and then passing it to the machine that already knows how to write: the base Writer.

So, basically, your write() method should look like this:

```
public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) {
    // transform the dirty car into a washed car
    char[] encodedChars = encode(cbuf, off, len);

    // paint the washed car
    baseWriter.write(encodedChars, 0, encodedChars.length);
}
```

Hopefully, this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll look into it tomorrow, because I'm too tired at the moment, but i changed my code a fair bit aswell.

Comment: Your analogy made it more clear and now i know how to tackle the problem.
So the constructor accepts my cipher object which contains the various values like the String (?) and the Writer is simply writing everything into a file or a stream.

I somehow dont understand the difference between my cipher and the Writer. Isn't the Writer supposed to hold my encoded Strings?What does the cipher do?

Thank you very much

Comment: Okay i tried out your answer, but I don't fully understand the reason behind the AtbashCipher "cipher" and also
    char [] encodedChars = encode(cbuf, off, len); 
Do i need to change my encode/decode methods, so I can give it the required arguments? Our encode method is (as far as i know) only supposed to receive the char.

Thank you for the help

Comment: If it can encode a char, then you can use it to encode several chars, can't you? You just need to call encode() on every char you want to encode. A Writer has a method `write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`, so you'll need to implement that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved it, but didn't have time to reply.
The result is in the edit, it works and the problem is solved :)